# Get Direction between two pins using google maps in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

using xamarin forms ,PCL

i searched a lot about a way that show Directions between two points(locations) using google maps inside the same App without directing to google maps native APP.

i tried External Maps plugin by James Montemagno and it works but i need direction appears within the same App rather than google maps APP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a 3rd party service to receive directions between 2 points, such as [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro).

From here, you can overlay the coordinates over the map.

Comment: can you please share an example?